# AngularUI Bootstrap Modal template file

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui

I am trying to implement Bootstrap Modal from http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ (pls. search for Modal). The templateUrl refers to myModalContent.html. But, I could not find this file. Can someone shed some light on this file?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a template written in a script tag

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="item in items">
                <a ng-click="selected.item = item">{{ item }}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        Selected: <b>{{ selected.item }}</b>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, it explains how it is tied together.

Comment: you are welcome, you can mark it as answered by clicking the tick mark to the answer